# Primality test program

Tags: c++, performance, beginner, primes

I am fairly new to programming and even newer to C++ but I am currently in a class for scientific computing, and our task from two weeks ago was to improve the speed of a primality test program. I regrettably do not have the original code because I wrote over it, but the long and short was that program selects 100,000 integers from 100,000 to 999,999 and checks all numbers from 2 to less than the number.

Needless to say, it took over 17 seconds to run. My code was able to get it down to ~74 milliseconds. I handed in my code last week but it's been bugging me that I don't know if I got it as fast as it could go.

(The area I made is at the bottom, at `int CountPrimes`)

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

int CountPrimes(unique_ptr<vector<int>> const &samples);

seed_seq seed{ 2016 };
default_random_engine generator{ seed };
uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(100000, 999999);

int main()
{
    const auto samples{ make_unique<vector<int>>(100000) };

    for (auto &sample : *samples)
        sample = distribution(generator);

    cout.imbue(std::locale(""));
    cout << "Searching vector of "
        << samples->size() << " integers..."
        << endl;

    auto startTime = system_clock::now();

    int numPrimes = CountPrimes(samples);

    auto stopTime = system_clock::now();

    auto totalTime = duration_cast<milliseconds>(stopTime - startTime);

    cout << "Number of Primes: " << numPrimes << endl;
    cout << "Total run time (ms): " << totalTime.count() << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


int CountPrimes(unique_ptr<vector<int>> const &samples)
{
    int numPrimes{};
    for (const auto &sample : *samples) {
        bool isPrime = true;
        int n{ 2 };
        int m{ 3 };
        if (sample % n == 0)
        {
            isPrime = false;
        }
        while (m < sample && m < 990)
        {
            if (sample % m == 0)
            {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
            m += 2;
        }

        if (isPrime)
            numPrimes++;
    }
    return numPrimes;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Your `CountPrimes` function wrongly returns `3` (instead of the correct answer `0`) when given the input `{982081, 988027, 994009}`. Can you see why?

---

Once you get down into dozens-of-milliseconds time ranges, it makes sense to increase the size of your test case so that you can distinguish real algorithmic improvements from noise. I recommend using 10,000,000 integers in your vector instead of 100,000, so that your runtimes are back up in the whole numbers of seconds instead of faster-than-human-reaction-time. A change that takes your runtime from 3.5 seconds to 1.5 seconds is vastly more likely to be a real optimization than a change that takes your reported runtime from 75 milliseconds to 20 milliseconds.

---

```
seed_seq seed{ 2016 };
default_random_engine generator{ seed };
uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(100000, 999999);
```

Global variables are evil. In this case, these variables are used only by `main`; so you should make them local to `main`. (If you still wanted them to be statically allocated instead of stack-allocated, you could qualify them with `static`; but protip: there's no reason to do that.)

---

```
int CountPrimes(unique_ptr<vector<int>> const &samples)
```

Stylistically, most C++ programmers would write this as

```
int CountPrimes(const std::unique_ptr<std::vector<int>>& samples)
```

(having internalized the advice that `using namespace std;` is a bad habit, and finding `const X&` easier to read than `X const &`). Your mileage may vary.

However, *definitely* you should not be using `unique_ptr` here. You have three indirections here where only one is needed:

- The actual data is in a buffer on the heap...
- which is pointed to by a pointer wrapped in a `std::vector`...
- which is pointed to by a pointer wrapped in a `std::unique_ptr`...
- which is pointed to by the reference argument to `CountPrimes`.

Instead of all this indirection, I recommend either the "standard" two levels of indirection:

```
int CountPrimes(const std::vector<int>& samples)
```

or if you can use the [C++ Core Guidelines support library](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md), you could dispense with one more level:

```
int CountPrimes(gsl::span<int> samples)
```

Anyway, get rid of that `unique_ptr`. It's not buying you anything. And as a good rule of thumb: passing any kind of smart pointer by reference is just as much of a code smell as passing a core-language pointer by reference. If you find yourself doing it, something is probably wrong with your design!

---

```
int numPrimes{};
```

is IMHO a needlessly convoluted way to write

```
int numPrimes = 0;
```

Likewise,

```
int n{ 2 };
if (sample % n == 0)
{
    isPrime = false;
}
```

is IMHO a needlessly complicated way to write

```
if (sample % 2 == 0) {
    continue;
}
```

When you know the input isn't prime, any further work you do after that point is wasted. Don't spend time looping on `m` if you're just going to throw that work away in the end.

---

If I were writing this code, I'd make a helper function `bool IsPrime(int x)` that just returns `true` if `x` is prime; and then my `CountPrimes` function could be

```
int CountPrimes(const std::vector<int>& v)
{
    int result = 0;
    for (auto&& x : v) {
        if (IsPrime(x)) ++result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Notice the complete lack of `goto`, `break`, or `continue` in this program; that is, I'm enabling the use of *[structured programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming)* by breaking my code down into subroutines.

The only reason *not* to arrange your program logically in this way is if you expect to get some benefit from logically arranging the computations a different way. For example, maybe we could exploit SSE vectorized instructions to do the computation four times faster, something like this:

```
int CountPrimes4x(const int *abcd)
{
    // use some _mm_... intrinsics or something
}

int CountPrimes(const std::vector<int>& v)
{
    int result = 0;
    assert(v.size() % 4 == 0);
    for (size_t i=0; i < v.size(); i += 4) {
        result += CountPrimes4x(&v[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Problem is, [there's no fast integer division instruction on x86,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31575833/fastest-method-of-vectorized-integer-division-by-non-constant-divisor) so we might not come up with anything better than the plain old (slow) (non-vectorized) integer division we started with.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, I really don't know anything about C++ or it's syntax so this is really helpful, honestly thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that, since you have a series of numbers to check for primality, that making a vector with all the indexes that are prime set to true would mean only finding primes once, instead of for each odd number.  Using a Sieve of Eratosthenes, makes this process very fast and efficient.

```
vector<bool> GetPrimes( int target )
{
    int sieveBound = (int)( target - 1 );
    int upperSqrt = ( (int)sqrt( target ) );
    vector<bool> primeBits(sieveBound,true);
    for ( int i = 3; i <= upperSqrt; i += 2 )
    {
        if ( primeBits[i] )
        {
            int step = i * 2;
            for ( int j = i * i; j <= sieveBound; j += step )
            {
                primeBits[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    return primeBits;
}
```

This algorithm has been optimized to ignore all the even indexes, since that is easily checked.
Now checking your samples is a matter of identifying only the odd numbers and seeing if the index is true:

```
vector<bool> primes = GetPrimes( 1000000 );
int count = 0;
for ( int i : samples )
{
    if (i % 2 != 0 && primes[i] )
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```